# What is the difference between "Local Linker Symbols" & "Local Program Variables"?

Tags: linker, symbols, elf

I want to know the difference between "Local Linker Symbols" & "Local Program Variables"?

I'm reading a book which has this:

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/9816/symbols.jpg](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/9816/symbols.jpg)

What does each mean? Any examples?

Answer (score 4):

```
/* This function has global scope within this file (module). It is represented 
 * by a "local linker symbol", since the linker will need to resolve its address 
 * if it is referenced by any other function.
 */
static void some_function()
{
    /* These "local program variables" are of no interest to the linker 
     * since they are not visible outside the current function, so no other 
     * part of the program can possibly reference them.
     */
    int a, b, c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Local Linker symbols are defined and referenced exclusively by a module.

Basically static variable and function are linker symbols and those variables or functions are not visible to other module except itself and those variables and functions are included in symbol table as local symbol in relocatable object module.

Local variables are variables defined locally which means they are not global variables.